# what's a better way to write javascript:void(0)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's a better or correct way to write the following:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick ="$('p').show()">click here</a>
```

Comment: Did you really put jQuery code in an `onclick` attribute?! Also look at the various questions turned up by this search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+void+0

Answer (score 7):

If you're using jQuery, the proper way would be:

**html**

```
<a href="#">Link</a>
```

**jQ**

```
$('a').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); $('p').show(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just omit the `href` entirely:

```
<a onclick ="$('p').show()>click here</a>
```

Comment: Then the `a` won't be an `a:link` anymore.

Comment: True, but it still answers to `a` in CSS :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery, use it at its full potential:

```
<a id="your-id">click here</a>

<script>
$('#your-id').click(function() {
    $('p').show();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `#` and `return false` in the onclick handler.

`return false` prevents the URL from being followed. An anchor to `#` points to the current page, so that it makes sense to open/bookmark the link.

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('p').show();return false;">click here</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The semantically correct thing to do here is to use a button tag instead of an a tag. It is bad practice to use javascript:void(0) in a link. Shoot, it's bad practice to include any inline JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Let it point to an URL which will make the desired element to show up by a server side view technology such as PHP/JSP/ASP so that the link still works for clients who have JS disabled.

E.g. in JSP:

```
<a href="currentPage.jsp?foo=1" class="foo">link</a>
<p class="bar ${param.foo != 1 ? 'hide' : ''}">paragraph</p>
```

with

```
$(".foo").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".bar").show();
    return false;
});
```